# Custom ribbon button on 'Edit Properties' dialog box ribbon?

Tags: development, ribbon, modal-dialog

In a nutshell - I would like a button somewhere on the ribbon (custom action?) that, when clicked, will form a string which includes the current web's ID and the list item ID.

How do I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you current selected items:

```
SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
```

and this will give you ID of current *SPWeb*:

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext();
var web = ctx.get_web();
ctx.load(web);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(function() {
  var id = web.get_id().toString();
  console.log(id);
});
```

When creating Ribbon buttons I usually put these in a separate file and call them from *Command*, like this (*mylib.js*):

```
window.myLib = {
  ribbonClick: function() {
    // Do stuff
  }
};
```

and then call this from the definition of your custom Ribbon button (*Elements.xml*):

```
<CommandUIHandlers>
  <CommandUIHandler Command="MyRibbonCommand" 
    CommandAction="javascript: window.myLib.ribbonClick();" />
</CommandUIHandlers>
```

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better answer, thanks a lot.